# How to rename a file with string format in C#?

Tags: c#, file, io

This is the situation:
I created a new file name using the string format like:

```
string newFileName = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}.txt", FileInfo.Year,
            FileInfo.Month, FileInfo.Day, FileInfo.Time);
```

and I have another(old) file with a path:  `string path = @"C:\Users\Public\fileName.txt"`
I would like to change or move the old --> the new. How to do that? Is it possible to change the path of the new?
Is there anyone who can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: `System.IO.File.Move`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string path = @"C:\Users\Public\fileName.txt";

 if (File.Exists(path))
            File.Move(path, "DestinationFilePath");
```

Comment: Rather than just posting code, it is more helpful to others if you include a brief explanation of how it solves the problem as well.